# Regex to find next word (which contains special character) after given word

Tags: c#, regex

I am facing problem with writing REGEX to get desired output from a string.

I have a string like `string simpleInput = @"Website address www.yahoo[mail].com AND Following is the";`

I want to specify "address" word and in result want the next word after it, i.e.`"www.yahoo[mail].com"`

I have written following piece of code.

```
string pattern = @"address (?<after>\w+)";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(simpleInput, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string nextWord = string.Empty;
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    nextWord = match.Groups["after"].ToString();
}
Console.WriteLine("Word is: " + nextWord );
```

This gives me output as:
Word is: www

Where as I expect output to be www.yahoo[mail].com

Can anyone please help?
I tried with \D+, that gives me entire string.. till the end of string, so gives additional text like "AND Following is the" also comes in result.

Where as I just wanted the single word "www.yahoo[mail].com"

Answer (score 1):

`\w+` doesn't match `.` or some other characters in the string you want to match. Try using `\S+` instead which means non-space characters:

```
string pattern = @"address (\S+)";
```